# What is the concept of Shortest Sub-string Match in Unix Shell?

Tags: bash, shell, string

I'm using following script for Shortest Sub-string Match in String handling.

```
filename="bash.string.txt"

echo ${filename#*.}
```

It gives following output.

```
string.txt
```

Here is an explanation of above example (Link: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation):

> The above example deletes the shortest match of $substring from front
>   of $string. In the first echo statement substring ‘*.’ matches the
>   characters and a dot, and # strips from the front of the string, so it
>   strips the substring “bash.” from the variable called filename.

Then I changed the code as below:

```
filename="bashshell.string.txt"

echo ${filename#*.}
```

I just extended the first string from **bash.** to **bashshell.**
and expecting the output "bashshell.txt" according to explanation given above. 
But instead it gives me same output as first example.

i.e. `string.txt`

So do I misunderstood the concept? If yes than how it actually works?

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial's use of the word "substring" is slightly misleading.  When using `${variable#pattern}`, we're dealing with matching and deleting a *prefix string* (and with `${variable%pattern}` a *suffix string*).

You removed the shortest prefix string matching `*.` from the two strings `bash.string.txt` and `bashshell.string.txt`.  The result for both strings is the same, `string.txt`, because the pattern `*.` matches up to and including the first dot in the string.

The POSIX standard [defines this particular parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) as

> `${parameter#[word]}`
>
> Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern. The *word* shall be expanded to produce a *pattern*. The parameter expansion shall then result in *parameter*, with the smallest portion of the prefix matched by the *pattern* deleted. If present, word shall not begin with an unquoted `#`.

Had you wanted to get the result `bashshell.txt`, you would have had to remove the string `.string` or `string.` from the middle of the string.  This could be done in two steps with standard parameter expansions:

```
suffix=${filename##*.}          # remove everything to the *last* dot
echo "${filename%%.*}.$suffix"  # remove everything from the first dot and add suffix
```

The `##` and `%%` variations of the parameter expansion removes the *longest* matching prefix and suffix strings respectively.

Alternatively with `bash`:

```
echo "${filename/string./}"
```

This removes the (first occurrence of the) given string anywhere within the value of `$filename`.

Answer (score 3):

> So do I misunderstood the concept? If yes than how it actually works?

Yes the notation `${var#*.}` is removing everything from the beginning of the string up to the character dot (`.`). It's doing what you asked of it, your pattern was star dot:

```
*.
```

So it will match everything up to the 1st dot from the start of the string, the one after the word `bash`.

```
bash.string.txt
    ^---------------- it's splitting here
```

#### Examples

```
$ str="bash.string.txt"
$ echo "${str#*.}"
string.txt

$ str="bash1.string.txt"
$ echo "${str#*.}"
string.txt

$ str="bash1.string1.txt"
$ echo "${str#*.}"
string1.txt
```

See when I put the 1 on the left side of the 1st `.`. This notation is truncating everything up to the 1st dot.

Comment: compared to `${str##*.}` which will replace everything until the **last** dot.